# Available(Free) Disk Space in Linux shows negative?

Tags: c, linux, diskspace, odroid

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

int GET_DISK_SPACE()
{
  struct statvfs sbuf;
  statvfs("/home/odroid", &sbuf);
  printf("Bytes left:%ld\n", sbuf.f_frsize*sbuf.f_bavail);

}
```

Wrote this simple function to get disk space on my linux machine and it returns negative value. 
original: `-89366528`

Then I added a simple text file with Size: `877 bytes | Size on disk: 4.00 KB`

and the value changed to `-89370624`

Then duplicated the file and got `-89374720`
These numbers don't make any sense. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
When I run `df -h` this is what I get

[image]

Comment: Probably should be `%lu` instead of `%ld`.

Comment: Oh, and `int GET_DISK_SPACE()` doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: This multiplication `sbuf.f_frsize*sbuf.f_bavail` also renders the number quite large on most modern systems. Why multiply size by available space?

Comment: @FredLarson changing to unsigned, I'm getting 4205584384 which is 3GB but df -h shows at least 24G available on one of the directories. 

Is my code incorrect?

Comment: `f_frsize*sbuf.f_bavail` makes no sense...

Comment: Should be multiplying by f_bsize instead of f_frsize.  And the format specifier given to `printf` is wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt same number as result 4205580288

Comment: I just realized we're looking at free space, not file sizes.

Comment: You should also check the return value of `statvfs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure that you aren't experiencing arithmetic overflow, and don't have a format string mismatch, use `long long` explicitly:

```
unsigned long long num_bytes = sbuf.f_bsize;
num_bytes *= sbuf.f_bavail;
printf("Bytes available: %llu\n", num_bytes);
```

As long as your expression's type is dependent on the structure member types, which are typedefs, it will be impossible to pick the correct format string.  Since `printf` is varargs, the compiler won't automatically convert to the correct type.  Introducing a helper variable allows you to be absolutely sure of the width of the parameter passed to `printf`.

Also, check the return value from `statvfs` to make sure these values actually mean something.  If you got an error, they won't be good for anything.

Comment: `struct statvfs sbuf;
    statvfs("/home/odroid", &sbuf);
    unsigned long long num_bytes = sbuf.f_bsize;
    num_bytes *= sbuf.f_bavail;
    printf("Bytes available: %llu\n", num_bytes);` doing this i got 23GB which sounds correct. thanks